# Can i show user online using flutter

Tags: flutter

Am using flutter and I really want to know how to show when the users are online or offline. I have created a chat app but now my biggest problem lies in showing if they are online or offline

Comment: Can you add some clarification? Some of your code? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty issue do one thing in your firebase collection

```
          USER where are users exit, make a field bool "status".
```

and if user is active make that field true otherwise make it false.